# I can not install forever or pm2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04, forever, pm2

I'm trying to install forever or pm2 in ubuntu 14.04 for a Sails app and the install start with the next message:

```
[...............] normalizeTree: sill install loadCurrentTree
```

...but not continue from this.

I'm installing with:
sudo npm install forever -g
sudo npm install pm2 -g

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a connectivity problem. My AWS security rules were blocking 'npm install'. I edit my outbound security rules to let all traffic temporally and now I could install forever.